# MvvmCross - How to Add Custom Modal Transition

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvm, mvvmcross

I am working on a project using MvvmCross and Xamarin. I am trying to add a custom transition when presenting and dismissing my modal view. Currently I am presenting it this way:

```
[MvxModalPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true, ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom)]
public partial class MyView : MvxViewController
{
```

and dismissing it this way:

```
NavigationController.DismissModalViewController(true);
```

So I have my animation ready, but I am assuming that I need to set the transition delegate to the one I've created. How do I do this?

I am fairly new to MvvmCross, so any tips and tricks are very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Am not sure, what you actually want to achieve here.

If you are looking for syntax help. This should be something like this.

```
this.NavigationController.TransitioningDelegate = new MyOwnDelegate();


  internal class MyOwnDelegate : IUIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
    {
        public IntPtr Handle => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

But normally people use, this one. I am also giving some syntax if that helps

```
this.NavigationController.Delegate = new NavigationControllerDelegate();



 public class NavigationControllerDelegate : UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    public NavigationControllerDelegate(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }
    public NavigationControllerDelegate()
    {
    }
    public override IUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning GetAnimationControllerForOperation(UINavigationController navigationController, UINavigationControllerOperation operation, UIViewController fromViewController, UIViewController toViewController)
    {
        var fromVcConformA = fromViewController as ICustomTransition;
        var fromVCConFromB = fromViewController as IWaterFallViewControllerProtocol;
        var fromVCCConformc = fromViewController as IHorizontalPageViewControllerProtocol;

        var toVcConformA = toViewController as ICustomTransition;
        var toVCConfromB = toViewController as IWaterFallViewControllerProtocol;
        var toVCCConformc = toViewController as IHorizontalPageViewControllerProtocol;

        if ((fromVcConformA != null) && (toVcConformA != null) && ((fromVCConFromB != null && toVCCConformc != null) || (fromVCCConformc != null && toVCConfromB != null)))
        {
            var transition = new CustomTransition();
            transition.presenting = operation == UINavigationControllerOperation.Pop;
            return transition;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe you answered it, but just to clarify, I was asking how to apply the transition delegate to my view. I have a delegate and transition already created.